# Load Post into DIV with Ajax

Tags: functions, ajax

I'm loading posts via Ajax into a div that I have set up on index page.

**index page loop:**

```
 <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div>
       <button class="post-link" rel="<?php the_ID(); ?>"> ADD </button>
       <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
       <a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

**Div:**

```
<div id="post-container"></div>
```

**script:**

```
<Script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    $(".post-link").click(function(){
        var post_link = $(this);

        $("#post-container").html("loading...");
        $("#post-container").load(post_link);
    return false;
    });

 });
</script>
```

**How to add posts into div with ajax and assign them specific post format?**

Comment: can you give action callback codes you used for this ajax request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to [register a action callback](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)) for you ajax request.
Secondly you need to send all ajax request to `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` (both `GET` and `POST`).
And lastly you need to modify your javascript a little to pass the `action` parameter which will trigger the callback. and `var post_link = $(this);` doesn't gives the post id from rel attribute you should use `var post_link = $(this).attr("rel");`

You can get the ajax url by `admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' );` in your theme. and use [javascript localization](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to get inside your js.

Everything else looks good on your index.php

**Example**

*JavaScript*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    $(".post-link").click(function(){
        var post_id = $(this).attr("rel");
        $("#post-container").html("loading...");
        //$("#post-container").load(post_link+"?action=load_more_post&pid="+post_id);
        // update: .load() should send request to ajax url not the post url
        $("#post-container").load(ajax_url+"?action=load_more_post&pid="+post_id);
    return false;
    });
});
```

*PHP (in your theme's function.php)*

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_load_more_post', 'load_more_post_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load_more_post', 'load_more_post_callback' );

function load_more_post_callback() {
    if( isset($_GET["pid"]) ){
        $post = get_post( $_GET["pid"] );
        if( $post instanceof WP_Post ) {
            echo '<h1 class="post_title">'.$post->post_title.'</h1>';
        } else {
            // nothing found with the post id
        }
    } else {
        // no post id
    }
    wp_die();
}
```

Comment: post are not loading in div please check [TEST-LINK](http://www.cbleu.net/sites/farooq/)

Comment: i also want to use this for CPT and Max to load in post = 4, please adjust php.. Thanks

Comment: your `post_link` is not defined; and as your test-link showing your using inline javascript in footer please change `$("#post-container").load(post_link+"?action=load_more_post&pid="+post_id);` with `$("#post-container").load("<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>?action=load_more_post&pid="+post_id);`. and if you want to put this snippet in separate file please use **javascript localization**. see the answer.

Comment: How to load title+thumbnail, unable to load thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

To load a post into a div using Ajax, you can use the `.load()` method in jQuery. This method fetches the HTML content of the specified post and inserts it into the div with the specified id.

Here's an example of how you might modify your code to do this:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

    // Set the ajax cache to false
    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});

    // Handle the click event for the post link buttons
    $(".post-link").click(function(){
        var post_link = $(this);

        // Set the text of the post container to "loading..." while the post is being fetched
        $("#post-container").html("loading...");

        // Load the post using the post_link button's rel attribute, which contains the post's ID
        $("#post-container").load(post_link.attr('rel'));

        // Prevent the default link behavior
        return false;
    });

 });
</script>
```

To specify a particular post format for the loaded post, you can pass the post format as a query string parameter to the `.load()` method. For example, to load the post in the "aside" format, you could use the following code:

```
$("#post-container").load(post_link.attr('rel') + "?format=aside");
```

You can change the "aside" parameter to any other post format that you want to use for the loaded post.